# Correct usage of assertRaises in Python unit tests

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use `assertRaises()` in Python unit testing. I have a `ValueError` in my function that gets raised. However, when testing in my unit tests, I'm getting mixed results with two different ways of using `assertRaises().

When I write the test like this, it works:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    def test_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            func(a)
```

However, if I write my test like below, it does not work even though the `ValueError` gets raised:

```
    def test_error(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, func(a))
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why one way would work and the other wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asserRaises` method takes a variable argument list, where the first argument is the function object, and the optional other arguments are the function arguments. You have to call it either this way (the usual way):

```
def test_error(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, func, a)
```

Or using a lambda:

```
def test_error(self):
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: func(a))
```

The problem with your call is that it would execute your function before calling `assertRaises`, as the *result* of the function call instead of the function itself is passed as an argument - so the exception would occur before `assertRaises` could handle it.

Having said that, I would always prefer the context manager variant, as it is better readable.